# Compile cling bug

Tags: llvm, cling

I'm trying to compile Cling (followed [build instructions](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/cling-build-instructions))  and i'm unable to find bug reports maillist:

```
llvm[4]: Compiling AutoSynthesizer.cpp for Debug+Asserts build
llvm[4]: Compiling AutoloadCallback.cpp for Debug+Asserts build
/Users/asmirnov/Documents/dev/src/llvm_cling/tools/cling/lib/Interpreter/AutoloadCallback.cpp:16:67: error: 
      expected a class or namespace
      = sema.getDiagnostics().getCustomDiagID (DiagnosticsEngine::Level::Warning,
                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
1 error generated.
make[4]: *** [/Users/asmirnov/Documents/dev/src/llvm_cling_build/tools/cling/lib/Interpreter/Debug+Asserts/AutoloadCallback.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-enable-cxx11` configure option. Updated build tutorial after it.